# How to add 5 buttons into the applicationbar WP7.?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am working WP7 and I wanted to add 5 buttons into the ApplicationBar but it say too many list into the applicationbar so is there any workaround for that so that I can go ahead.!

Note :
I dont want to add the applicationmenubar item.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about making some of the less common buttons menu items? Like so:

```
<shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="my menu item" Click="beginAllocateVotes"/>
</shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
```

5 app bar buttons may look a bit crowded.

Comment: that is fine but my requirement is like this so we have to stick with this approach so is there any work around to achieve 5 buttons in applicationbar.

Comment: I'm not really sure. I'll let someone else answer that, I was just suggesting something in case you couldn't find a work around